# I can not use private repo as npm dependency in circleci deploys

Tags: node.js, git, github, ssh, circleci

I'm using circle ci to deploy a serverless built in **nodejs**. And I added as dependency of the main repo,a private github repo. E.g:

```json
// package.json
.....
"dependencies": {
    "my-private-github-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:company-name/my-private-github-repo.git",
    .....
},
.....
```

The problem is that I need to give access the deploy process to read and clone the private repo when `npm install` runs

I have configured my ssh user-keys in circle ci,I followed the steps in this documentation: [creating-a-bitbucket-user-key](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#creating-a-bitbucket-user-key), and I m also adding it in my **config.yml** like this:

```html
  // .circleci/config.xml
  ....
  steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "My fingerprint"
  ....
```

But during the cicd it throws this message: **'There are no configured ssh keys to install'**

[There are no configured ssh keys to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66QNs.png)

and, of course, `npm install` fails because can not access to the repo

Any clue? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014071554-There-are-no-configured-ssh-keys-to-install-) mentions:

> When this error appears, it typically means that the ssh keys have not been configured in all locations.
> SSH keys will need to be set in both the project setting's page and within the config.yml.

Just in case, double-check the URL `https://app.circleci.com/settings/project/github/<your organization name>/<project name>/ssh` and see if it matches `Checkout SSH Keys` page mentioned in the [official documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#creating-a-bitbucket-user-key)